# IBM WebSphere Application Server wsadmin returning only first result out of 6 in script

Tags: python, websphere, jython

When attempting to get the status of applicaitons in WebSphere Application Server, I expect there to be multiple returned mbeans. However, WAS is only returning the first result and discarding the rest of them it seems.

```
[wasadmin@servername01 ~]$ Run_wsadmin.sh -f wsadmin_Check_App_Status.py
WASX7209I: Connected to process "dmgr" on node PRDDMGR using SOAP connector;  The type of process is: DeploymentManager
WASX7026W: String "type=Application,name=AMTApp,*" corresponds to 6 different MBeans; returning first one.
```

The script I'm running looks like this:

```
app_name = AppName
app_status = AdminControl.completeObjectName('type=Application,name=' + app_name + ',*').split('\n')

for status in app_status :
  print( status )
# end of For status in app_status
```

Is there some setting in WebSphere, or do I need to import some special library into my script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the doc of `AdminControl.completeObjectName()`

> Use the completeObjectName command to create a string representation of a complete ObjectName value that is based on a fragment. This command does not communicate with the server to find a matching ObjectName value. **If the system finds several MBeans that match the fragment, the command returns the first one.**

So that function is behaving as expected.

**Instead**:
In this situation, it sounds like you want to use `AdminControl.queryNames()`, which is built for returning a list of results that match your query.

For example:

```
app_name = AppName
app_status = AdminControl.queryNames('type=Application,name=' + app_name + ',*').split('\n')

for status in app_status :
  print( status )
```

Source: [Commands for the AdminControl object using wsadmin scripting](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rxml_admincontrol.html)